# Don't save record after install sorcery or formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic, sorcery

I try to rails console for me table object but when I install sorcery or formtastic (i don't know) my record don't save.

Model

```
class Depositi < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :code, :description
 validates_presence_of :code, :message => 'Code required!'
end
```

View

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@depositi) do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs 'Dati Deposito' do %>
    <%= f.input :code, :label => 'Codice Deposito:' , :wrapper_html => { :class => 'fl' }, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :description, :label => 'Descrizione:', :wrapper_html => { :class => 'fl'},  :input_html => {:size => '15'} %> 
    <% end %>
    <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button, :label => 'Save' %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

this is my debug:

```
utf8    ✓
authenticity_token  kVQ5OOkmGxqoZgbvteJ80M+lLHwopWEY0SI4YetQYsg=
depositi    {"code":"001","description":"Test this is test"}
button  
action  new
```

Controller

```
def create
@depositi = Depositi.new(params[:depositi])

respond_to do |format|
  if @depositi.save
    format.html { redirect_to @depositi, notice: 'Record salvato con successo!' }
    format.json { render json: @depositi, status: :created, location: @depositi }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @depositi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This record don't save! I'm property login, i don't have error..why don't save?

---

RESOLVED: The problem was in my view up of  <%= semantic_form_for(@depositi) do |f| %>
I write  that was in conflict with formtastic render form.

Comment: you have only submitted the record but not saved it. Use your controller to save it.

Comment: In fact I use the controller.

Comment: If you used it, then it's code is the only thing that we need in order to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry you're right...

Comment: Your code looks correct. Also there is no need to put `required => true` as you already put validation at model level. Try to create the record directly by doing: `@depositi = Depositi.create(params[:depositi])`

Comment: I try but don't work. I'm confused...

Comment: Don't get confused. This is common way of saving records. You may be missing something somewhere like table constraints, model level scope, etc.